# convert string value to charsequence and show it in notification in android

Tags: android, string, notifications, charsequence

I want to show the result of this function in notification.

```
public class TimerService extends Service {
    public String timeString;
... // service methodd
public class CountingDownTimer extends CountDownTimer{
             public CountingDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) {

            timeString = String.format("%02d", 5000/ 60)
                    + ":" + String.format("%02d", 5000% 60);
                ...
        }
...// at the end of TimerService class
                    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentText(timeString).build();
```

but unfortunately nothing(null) show in the notification. what can I do? how can I convert String value to char sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem before. you should create new method and put notification in it.

```
private void setupNotification(String s) {}
```

The most important thing is that you should send `timestring` from `CountingDownTimer` to `setupNotification`. so do it like this:

```
public class CountingDownTimer extends CountDownTimer{
    public String timeString=null;

         public CountingDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) {
        timeString = String.format("%02d", 5000/ 60)
                + ":" + String.format("%02d", 5000% 60);
       setupNotification(timeString);

    }

private void setupNotification(String s) {
    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentText(s)
}
```

I hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
String s="STR";
CharSequence cs = s;  // String is already a CharSequence
```

so you just pass `timeString` to `setContentText`

**Edit:**

it seems you call notification.setContentText() before CountingDownTimerstarts.

call `notification`
inside `OnFinish()`

```
 public CountingDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
            timeString = String.format("%02d", l / 60)
                    + ":" + String.format("%02d", l % 60);

        // Add Here
        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                             .setContentText(timeString).build();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start();
```

here notification set after Countdown timer finished

Comment: I update my question and post some details. would you please check it.

Comment: oh no! I want to show counter in notification during counting.